# How can I make my multi-monitor setup wrap around?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have a 4-monitor setup on Win7 Ultimate (nVidia 8800GTS + 6600GT), and I'm experimenting with various layouts for optimal awesomeness.

One thing that really bugs me is the sheer distance that the mouse pointer needs to travel horizontally to get from the left edge of the left screen to the right edge of the right screen. It would be tremendously awesome if I could set it up to wrap around so that if I move the cursor all the way left it wraps around to the right again. Unfortunately, I can't for the life of me find any way to make this happen.

Googling around gives a Mac utility that does exactly what I want; someone also suggested connecting the computer to itself with [Synergy](http://symless.com/synergy), which seems awfully kludgey and I never got it working anyway. Is this possible with Windows? I'm happy to get my hands dirty with some COM scripting if necessary, but I don't really know the Windows API...

Comment: The company I work for specializes in high-end multiple monitor power user workstations and I've never seen anything that would do this in Windows that isn't extremely kludgy, I'm afraid.  I like Xantec's suggestion as a neat alternative though.

Comment: I finally bought a Mac and [Wraparound](http://www.digicowsoftware.com/app/Wraparound) works wonders =)

Comment: Nice! Wish they had that for Windows.

Answer (score 5):

The closest i was able to find with a quick search was [this](http://graphics.cs.columbia.edu/projects/m3/index.html). it doesn't wrap but instead uses keyboard shortcuts to let you jump the mouse cursor to a different monitor.

Answer (score 3):

If you tell Windows that your monitors are in a 2x2 configuration rather than a 4x1 (ie tell it that two are above the other two) then you can move quickly to the further screens by moving the mouse off the top or bottom of the screen.

This does assume that you don't use apps that span across multiple screens, if generally keep your apps to one screen each (or remember how they're paired to span across two) then this could work quite neatly.

Comment: I'm going to have to agree with Thrawn on this one...at work, everyone in our department needs four monitors for the type of work we do. The default layout is 4x1, but after much use, I found this to be really inefficient. You have to move your head back and forth way too often and too much, and it's difficult to focus on anything other than one or two screens at once. Putting them in a 2x2 configuration allows you to get much more done and keep an eye on more things. It's improved my productivity. It may be difficult to find mounts for the monitors, but your neck will thank you for it.

Comment: TheEmpireNeverEnded:  FWIW, I suspect that GAThrawn’s suggestion is to keep the monitors *physically* in a 4×1 array, but to *tell the OS* that they are in a 2×2 configuration.   I imagine that this non-intuitive setup would be highly frustrating and infuriating to the user — for about two or three weeks.   Then he’d get accustomed to it, and would get the benefit of reduced mouse motion (moving the mouse *pointer* between the far edges by moving the *mouse* less than 2.5 screen widths) that he wants, albeit without the other benefits that you mention.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just set up some acceleration on your mouse (e.g. via Logicool mouse settings) and then a quick movement will send your cursor off to the far right screen in a flash.

It doesn't answer your question, but it might solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I tried CursorUS, and it only works on a single monitor.

If you try Edgeless 2 [(Download page)](http://www.fxc.btinternet.co.uk/assistive.htm) it allows you to wrap multi-screen, and choose to do so vertically, horizontally or both.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Super User. So far, you've only answers recommending this software. While they are valid answers, please read our [FAQ section on promotion](http://superuser.com/faq#promotion) - if you are affiliated in any way with the makers of Edgeless, you are required to disclose that in your answers. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work on my 2-monitor setup (wraps vertically but not horizontally). Closest yet though!

Comment: @nhinkle Thanks for the welcome! I am not affiliated with Edgeless (or specifically in this case Edgeless 2) in any way. I only posted this to return the favour as I found it with the help of this site (and it works!).

Answer (score 2):

I tried CursorUS and Edgeless2 with no luck on a dual-monitor set up.

[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) is for scripting and input automation. I was able to get wrap to work in both directions [using this custom script](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/34427-yet-another-mouse-wrapper-this-one-supports-multi-heads/).

Answer (score 2):

For those arriving here from Google, this is possible, for free, by performing the following actions:

1. Install AutoHotkey from here: https://www.autohotkey.com/download/
2. Navigate to your folder that you wish to store the script in
3. Right click in the folder, select new, then click "AutoHotkey Script"
4. Give it a name ending in ".ahk"
5. Right click the file and select "Edit Script"
6. Paste the "App" code found here: https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/34427-yet-another-mouse-wrapper-this-one-supports-multi-heads/ into the file you just created
7. You can now right click the file, and click "Run Script", or you can proceed to step 8 to run automatically on startup.
8. Press Ctrl + R and enter "shell:common startup" to have this start automatically for all users, or "shell:startup" to have this only start for the current user. Once you have input the command, press enter.
9. Right click on the script you created and select copy, then right click in your startup folder and select "Paste shortcut" (If you do not have permission to paste a shortcut here, you will need to change the folder's ownership and permission to be your current user).
10. Now restart your computer to have this take effect.

This will add an icon to your system tray allowing you to adjust the X and Y settings by right clicking the icon.

NOTE: I do not own, nor am affiliated with, AutoHotkey or the poster of the script. This information was just posted to assist those wishing to perform this operation.

---

Comment: Exactly what I needed and what I was looking for. I knew that this kind of thing was possible to do with AutoHotKey

Answer (score 0):

I can't verify that this works on a multi-monitor setup, but this little freeware tool might help you:
[CursorUS](http://www.loonies.narod.ru/cursorus.htm).

Answer (score -1):

[Input Director](http://www.inputdirector.com/) can do this when working with multiple machines. The feature doesn't seem to work when solo however. Perhaps a way can be discovered.

Answer (score -1):

For about three years I have used Actual Multiple Monitors software on the three horizontal monitors and it works great to do wraparound (all directions if desired) as well as a number of other multi monitor features

https://www.actualtools.com/articles/detail.php?ID=1322

Comment: Can you provide a source link for that?