# How to connect desktop of multiple displays

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I am currently looking for a way to connect the desktops of all my monitors. I am currently using 3 monitors side by side. The problem I am currently facing is when I move my mouse to either the left of the right monitor it eventually stops on one side of the monitor because there is no desktop to move to. What I want to do is connect my left and right monitors so that the mouse can seamlessly scroll through all my monitors continuously with no breaks. For instance I would be able to scroll my mouse to the left through my left-side monitor and have it appear on the right-side monitor. Thus eliminating the edges/barriers on the sides of the left and right side monitors.

I am currently using windows 10 with a EVGA GTX1070. Any help/advice/suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is showing on each of your screens? Are they connected to your computer? How? Have you looked at the Display Properties dialog in Windows?

Comment: You question might be a [duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/207218/how-can-i-make-my-multi-monitor-setup-wrap-around). But [this](https://superuser.com/a/708924/554708) will help you.

Comment: If I understand your question, you've got your monitors arranged such that you can move across them, but you want to be able to 'warp' from the right edge of the rightmost monitor to the left of the leftmost, by moving the cursor slightly more to the right (and vice versa).  Is this correct?

Comment: correct. I have monitors set up like this:                                                         [Monitor 3] [Monitor 1(main display)] [Monitor 2] and currently the mouse will stop at the leftmost edge of Monitor 3 and the rightmost edge of Monitor 2, I want to be able to "warp" from the rightmost edge of Monitor 3 to Monitor 2, vice versa. I appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This AutoHotKey script called [MouseWrapper](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/34427-yet-another-mouse-wrapper-this-one-supports-multi-heads/) is the best program I've found that does this.

If you don't have AutoHotKey installed, I've compiled and uploaded it [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=06659765225249069298). Just download and run the .exe.