# Three monitors and ability to drag mouse left or right

Tags: multiple-monitors, mouse

I have three screens (two external monitors and my laptop screen)...the order of my screens is (left to right) 3 (external),1 (laptop),2 (external).  From my #1 monitor,  I want to be able to drag either left or right, not right right or left left.  Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried the solutions at https://superuser.com/questions/207218/how-can-i-make-my-multi-monitor-setup-wrap-around? In general, search for "monitor wraparound".

Answer (score 2):

If you right click on your desktop and open up display settings, you'll see your three monitors listed. You can drag and drop the squares in the order you'd like.